# "Address of" (&) an array / address of being ignored be gcc?

Tags: c, gcc, pointers, addressof

I am a teaching assistant of a introductory programming course, and some students made this type of error:

```
char name[20];
scanf("%s",&name);
```

which is not surprising as they are learning... What is surprising is that, besides gcc warning, the code works (at least this part). I have been trying to understand and I wrote the following code:

```
void foo(int *v1, int *v2) {
  if (v1 == v2)
    printf("Both pointers are the same\n");
  else
    printf("They are not the same\n");
}

int main() {
  int test[50];
  foo(&test, test);
  if (&test == test)
    printf("Both pointers are the same\n");
  else
    printf("They are not the same\n");
}
```

Compiling and executing:

```
$ gcc test.c -g
test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:12: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘foo’ from incompatible pointer type
test.c:13: warning: comparison of distinct pointer types lacks a cast
$ ./a.out 
Both pointers are the same
Both pointers are the same
```

Can anyone explain why they are not different?

I suspect it is because I cannot get the address of an array (as I cannot have `& &x`), but in this case the code should not compile.

Edit: I know that an array by itself is the same as the address of the first element, but this is not related to this problem, I think. For example:

```
int main() {
  int a[50];
  int * p = a;
  printf("%d %d %d\n", p == a, p == &a[0], &p[0] == a);
  printf("%d %d %d\n", p == &a, &p == a, &p == &a);
}
```

prints:

```
$ ./a.out 
1 1 1
1 0 0
```

I don't understand why the second line begins with `1`.

Comment: Your edit indicates that you think there is some pointer stored along with the array. But that's not the case. An array consists *just* of its elements.

Comment: I knew that an array is just elements, that's why I thought it should not compile.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In your example, the array `test` is a block of 50 `ints`.  So it looks like this:

```
| int | int | ... | int |
```

When you apply the unary `&` operator to an array, you get the address *of the array*.  Just like when you apply it to anything else, really.  So `&test` is a pointer that points to that block of 50 `ints`:

```
(&test) -----------> | int | int | ... | int |
```

A pointer that points to an array of 50 ints has type `int (*)[50]` - that's the type of `&test`.

When you just use the name `test` in any place where it's not the operand of either the `sizeof` or unary-`&` operators, it is evaluated to a pointer to its first element.  So the `test` that you pass to `foo()` evaluates to a pointer to the `test[0]` element:

```
(test) -----------------\
                        v
(&test) -----------> | int | int | ... | int |
```

You can see that these both are pointing to the same address - although `&test` is pointing to the whole array, and `test` is pointing to the first element of the array (which only shows up in the different *types* that those values have).

Comment: I like the ascii art :) Now with that pic, it's easy to explain why adding `1` to `&test` moves beyond the array, and adding `1` to `test` moves only beyond the first element.

Answer (score 10):

Actually, they are different, they don't have the same type at least.

But in C, the address of the array is the same as the address of the
first element in the array that's why "they are not different", basically, they point to the same thing.

Comment: "the address of the array is the same as the address of the first element in the array"

I always knew that the array by itself (and *not* the address of the array) is the same as the address of the first element, i.e., `test` is exactly the same as `&test[0]`. I have just checked in K&R, and that's what is written there...

I will edit my question to add this.

Comment: @WhirlWind: No, it's *not* system-dependent.  Applying the address-of operator to an array has well-defined semantics - it must produce the address of the array itself.  The array is defined as a consecutive sequence of objects of the base type, and thus the address of the array and the address of the first object are the same place (but with different types).

Answer (score 6):

If You define an array like

```
char name[20];
```

`name` is implicitly convertible to `char*`, but `&name` is of the type `char (*)[20]` (a pointer to an array of 20 characters). The addresses are the same.

Check the address of `(&name + 1)`. It differs form `&name` by the  `sizeof(char [20])`.

Comment: Thanks, you made it easier to understand James McNellis answer.

Comment: The last sentence actually makes this the best answer here IMHO. If you understood how a `+ 1`  on a pointer in C increases the pointer address by the size of the type (`sizeof(*ptr)`), then this sentence basically explains it all :)

Answer (score 2):

The name of an array, in most circumstances, *evaluates* to the address of its initial element.  The two exceptions are when it is the operand of `sizeof` or the unary `&`.

The unary `&` gives the address of its argument.  The address of an array is the same as the address of its initial element, so `(void*)&array == (void*)array` will always be true.

`array`, when converted to a pointer to its initial element, has the type `T *`.  The type of `&array` is `T (*)[n]`, where `n` is the number of elements in the array.  Thus,

```
int* p = array;        // Works; p is a pointer to array[0]
int* q = &array;       // Doesn't work; &array has type int (*)[10]
int (*r)[10] = &array; // Works; r is a pointer to array
```

Comment: Thank you, I only knew the exception of sizeof.

Answer (score -3):

I believe this is a gcc optimization. Think about it.

- `&test` points to the address of `test`
- `test` points to the first element of `test` or `&test[0]`
- `[0]` is the same(for the most part) as `*`

So according to this `&test` **could** be different than `test` but gcc optimizes this away because there is no purpose of having an extra level of indirection at that point.

Comment: It's not a gcc optimisation - it is behaviour that is required by the C standard.

Comment: It seems like @Earlz is mistaken the meaning of &test exactly as I was.

Comment: @dba wow I was. The accepted answer for this completely clears it up