# What is the difference between these two parameters in C++?

Tags: c++, pointers

I am new to C++ and currently am learning about templates and iterators.
I saw some code implementing custom iterators and I'm curious to know what the difference between these two `iterator` parameters is:

```
iterator & operator=(iterator i) { ...   i.someVar }
bool operator==(const iterator & i) { ... i.someVar }
```

They implement the = and == operators for the particular iterator. Assuming the iterator class has a member variable 'someVar', why is one operator implemented using "iterator i" and another with "iterator & i"? Is there any difference between the two "i.someVar" expressions?

I googled a little and found this question
[Address of array - difference between having an ampersand and no ampersand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7707190/address-of-array-difference-between-having-an-ampersand-and-no-ampersand)

to which the answer was "the array is converted to a pointer and its value is the address of the first thing in the array." I'm not sure this is related, but it seems like the only valid explanation I could find.

Thank you!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pass by Reference / Value in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/410593/pass-by-reference-value-in-c)

Comment: Are you asking why an assignment operator would use a by-val parameter, while an equality comparison operator would use a const-reference parameter? There is a very good reason for this, but I'm not going to take the time to answer it if that isn't the question.

Comment: Disagree with Potatoswatter. The linked question is fairly generic, but `iterator::operator=(iterator)` is the assignment operator. That's a function which warrants specific consideration (Rule of Three, for instance).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the assignment operator `=` takes the iterator i as value, which means a copy of the original iterator is made and passed to the function so any changes applied to the iterator `i` inside the operator method won't affect the original.

the comparison operator `==` takes a constant reference, which denotes that the original object can't/shouldn't be changed in the method. This makes sense since a comparison operator usually only compares objects without changing them. The reference allows to pass a reference to the original iterator which lives outside the method. This means that the actual object won't be copied which is usually faster.

Comment: The assignment operator also does not change the value being assigned. The reason for pass by value here is probably move semantics, a topic beyond this discussion.

Comment: Thanks, this is clearer now. So &i is a reference to i and i is a copy of i.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: full ack

Answer (score 3):

`operator=` takes its argument by value (a.k.a. by copy). `operator ==` takes its argument by const reference (a.k.a. by address, albeit with a guarantee that the object will not be modified).

An iterator *may* be/contain a pointer into an array but it is not itself an array.

The ampersand (`&`) has different contextual meanings. Used in an expression, it behaves as an operator. Used in a declaration such as `iterator & i`, it forms part of the type `iterator &` and indicates that `i` is a reference, as opposed to an object.

For more discussion (with pictures!), see [Pass by Reference / Value in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/410593/pass-by-reference-value-in-c) and [What's the difference between passing by reference vs. passing by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373419/whats-the-difference-between-passing-by-reference-vs-passing-by-value#373429) (this one is language agnostic).

Comment: Thank you. It makes a lot of sense that == would take a const reference; comparing equality shouldn't involve changing the things being compared.

Comment: @mhy Yes, but assigning `a = b` also doesn't change `b`. The other function can also be written using `iterator const &` and was usually done so up until C++11; the difference is a matter of optimization.

Comment: @mhy prior to C++11 and move-semantics, it was entirely common (and still is to some degree) to use a param-copy-swap idiom for assignment operators. There are solid reasons behind this, including unifying copy-construction and assignment operator equivalency, as well as exception protection. It is somewhat beyond the scope of your question, but there are indeed logical reasons for using a by-value parameter for the rhs of an assignment operator. (and +1 on the answer)

Comment: @WhozCraig Param-copy-swap *is* move-semantic. The C++11 idiom does exactly the same thing (only difference is `swap` becomes `move`), but for most of the lifetime of C++98/03, most folks just defaulted to `const &` whether it was the best way or not.

Comment: @Potatoswatter really? I never considered it move, since clearly (to me, anyway) it was markedly different. the original rhs was left intact, so to me there was never a move. And I'm somewhat disappointed in the pervasive practice of *not* using it if it (const ref) is as wide-spread as you say it is. it seems such a natural idea, especially with classes that hold dynamic allocation. Heh. I learned something new today, thank you!.

Comment: @WhozCraig My last comment was wrong; the C++11 idiomatic assignment operator is implemented in terms of `swap` and is fully backward compatible with C++98. Don't worry about common practices; the gap between C++98 and C++11 wasn't stagnation but discovery of how to best use the language. The only change here is that C++11 provides you with a means to initialize the parameter object by destroying the argument. Anyway the implicitly-defined assignment operators don't work this way; the default is to have two overloads by reference.

Comment: Actually the `swap` in "copy&swap assignment` often compiled down to a move, as the assignment to a local variable was a dead store. That just optimized out.

Answer (score 1):

First, you don't have an address of an array here.

There's no semantic difference, unless you try to make a local change to the local variable `i`: `iterator i` will allow a local change, while `const iterator & i` will not.

Many people are used to writing `const type & var` for function parameters because passing by reference can be faster than by value, especially if `type` is big and expensive to copy, but in your case, an `iterator` should be small and cheap to copy, so there's no gain from avoiding copying. (Actually, having a local copy can enhance locality of reference and help optimization, so I would just pass small values by value (by copying).)

Comment: In the case of `const &`, there is no local variable at all, only a reference to some outside object.