# Ansi C:Is an array's name Stored as a pointer variable?

Tags: c, arrays, addressof

Say, I define an array:

```
int a[5];
```

And

```
a = &a[0];
```

is an address to the beginning of the array.

My question is, does `a` get stored someplace in memory like a pointer variable?
If so, when I try to print the address of `a` (`&a`), why do I get the same value as `a`?

Comment: Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7707190/address-of-array-difference-between-having-an-ampersand-and-no-ampersand

Comment: No, `a` is an array and not a pointer. Please read a C book. Such is definitively treated in the opening chapters about arrays.

Comment: Why do you not just try the assignment? What does your compiler say? Which output do you get from your program? And which type do you get for `int * p = a;` and `&a`?

Answer (score 1):

When you declare an array, the only storage that gets set aside is for the array elements themselves; no storage is set aside for a pointer to the first element.

When the compiler sees an array expression that isn't the operand of the `sizeof` or `&` operators, or isn't a string literal being used to initialize another array in a declaration, it will *convert* that array expression to a pointer expression, and the value of the pointer expression will be the address of the first element in the array.