# Pointer to an array giving incompatible pointer type warning

Tags: c, pointers

I'm getting `warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]` when i compile the following code:

```
int main() {
     int (*aptr) [5] = NULL;
     int arr[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};

     aptr = &arr[0];

     printf("aptr = %p\n arr = %p\n", aptr, &arr[0]);
     return 0;
}
```

I'm getting the correct output:

```
aptr = 0xbfcc2c64
arr = 0xbfcc2c64
```

But why am I getting the warning of incompatible pointer type?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does a pointer to array need to be cast before being passed as parameter to a function with array type argument?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17438175/why-does-a-pointer-to-array-need-to-be-cast-before-being-passed-as-parameter-to)

Answer (score 9):

You declared a pointer to the entire array. Why are you trying to make it point to the first *element*?

If you want to declare your `aptr` with `int (*)[5]` type, as in your example, and make it point to `arr`, then this is how you are supposed to set the pointer value

```
aptr = &arr;
```

What you have in your code now is an attempt to assign a `int *` value to a pointer of `int (*)[5]` type. These are different types, which is why you get the warning (which is a constraint violation, AKA error, actually).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the warning got removed. Just a small clarification, &arr is the address of the array. &arr[0] is address of 1st element in the array, conceptually both hold the same address.. isn't it? I tried to print the value &arr and &arr[0] which printed out, &arr = 0xbfa092e4
 &arr[0] =  0xbfa092e4
Please excuse if is dumb question.

Comment: @user2552690: Yes, purely numerically the address of the entire array is always the same as the address of its first element. Yet the types of the pointers are different. As one consequence of that, pointer arithmetic works differently for such pointers, for one example. Try printing `&arr + 1` and `&arr[0] + 1` and you will see the difference.

Comment: One more query. I was expecting that *aptr would give me the value of 1st element in the array. But I require **aptr to get the value of first element in the array. why?                              aptr = 0xbfdbf7e4
*(aptr) = 0xbfdbf7e4
**(aptr) = 1

Comment: @user2552690: Well, that would be the same mistake. `aptr` is a pointer to *the entire array*. This means that `*aptr` is the array itself, not the first element. In other words, `*aptr` is the same thing as `arr`. In order to get access to the first elelement you have to do `(*aptr)[0]` (cf. `arr[0]`) or `**aptr` (cf. `*arr`). There's nothing surprising here: in order to get that `aptr` you had to use `&` operator. Now, in order to get back to array you have to "compensate" for that `&` operator with an extra `*`.

Answer (score 1):

Array name itself give the base address it is not needed to use &arr.Moreover arr[0] represents the value at the first index.